# PHP: why is "Strict standards: Declaration of x should be compatible with y" applied to static methods?

Tags: php, warnings, strict

The PHP warning, "Strict standards: Declaration of x should be compatible with y" warns you if you write code like:

```
class A {
  function foo($x) {
    ..
  }
}
class B extends A {
  function foo() {
    ..
  }
}
```

This is sensible, because an object reference like "`$a`" which you think is an `A`, may at runtime turn out to be a `B`, so a dynamically dispatched method call like `$a->foo(3)` may end up calling `B::foo()` with the wrong number of arguments.

My question is: why is this same warning applied to static methods, which are not dynamically dispatched?

```
class X {
  static function bar($x) {
    ..
  }
}
class Y extends X {
  static function bar() {
    ..
  }
}
```

In this example, the function `Y::bar()` does not override `X::bar()`, so there is no reason to trigger the warning, but PHP still does. Why?

Comment: You're missing `class B extends A` and `class Y extends X` to make your examples legitimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Java, you can call static methods on an instance and they are dispatched by the runtime type of that object. So `Y::bar()` does in fact override `X::bar()` and it should be compatible.

```
<?php

class X {
  static function bar($x) {
    echo "X::bar() with x = $x\n";
  }
}
class Y extends X {
  static function bar() {
    echo "Y::bar()\n";
  }
}

echo "Static dispatch:\n";
X::bar(1);
Y::bar();

echo "Dynamic dispatch of a static method (surprise!):\n";
$arr = array(new X(), new Y());
foreach ($arr as $a) {
  $a::bar(1);
}
```

will output ([run it here](http://3v4l.org/phAWB)):

```
Warning: Declaration of Y::bar() should be compatible with X::bar($x) in /in/phAWB on line 12
Static dispatch:
X::bar() with x = 1
Y::bar()
Dynamic dispatch of a static method (surprise!):
X::bar() with x = 1
Y::bar()
```

(The [equivalent code](http://ideone.com/pVVd63) would not compile in Java.)

Answer (score 4):

Just like in Java, you can call static methods on an instance too. So there is still room for confusion.

Comment: Of course: you can dynamically dispatch static methods too: `$a::foo()`. What a language...

Comment: (This is not the same as Java btw: in Java the static call is statically dispatched (as seems sensible, given the name), based on the declared type of the object ref you call it on.)

Answer (score -2):

This warning has nothing to do with the real world.  Forget the academic examples and look at a real world example.   There are 1000's of LOCK manufacturers that make a door lock with a combination touchpad and a key override.   Do they use 2 deadbolts - one for the combination lock and one for the key lock?  NO.   The deadbolt lock is abstracted to the key lock and the combination lock.  That's REAL WORLD.  PHP ( who will quickly reject any bug reports on this subject) want to stick their heads in the sand on this.

```
class abstractLock
{
    private $locked = true;
    public function unlock()
    {
       $this->locked=false;
    }
    public function lockStatus()
    {
        if($this->locked) return "Locked\n";
        else return "Unlocked\n";
    }
}

class combinationLock extends abstractLock
{
    private $combination = '32-10-21'; // combination
    public function unlock($combination)        // unlock WITH combination
    {
        if($this->combination == $combination) parent::unlock();
    }
}

class paddleLock extends abstractLock
{
    private $key = '100,70,80,30,50,90,60,40,100'; // ridge heights
    public function unlock($key)                            // unlock WITH key
    {
        if($this->key == $key) parent::unlock();
    }
} 

$lock1 = new paddleLock();
echo "paddleLock is " . $lock1->lockStatus();
$lock1->unlock('100,70,80,30,50,90,60,40,100');
echo "paddleLock is " . $lock1->lockStatus();

$lock2 = new combinationLock();
echo "combinationLock is " . $lock2->lockStatus();
$lock2->unlock('32-10-21');
echo "combinationLock is " . $lock2->lockStatus();
```

PHP is not willing to even discuss this issue. So all my code will contain the following to eliminate this PHP *bug*:

```
// FIX PHP's bogus warning of: PHP Warning: Declaration of * should be compatible with
if (PHP_MAJOR_VERSION >= 7) {
    set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr) {
       return strpos($errstr, 'Declaration of') === 0;
    }, E_WARNING);
}
```

Comment: What does the "REAL WORLD" have to do with the rules of method inheritance in PHP? Your example breaks those rules, and PHP's warning is correct in your case. A method interface is a contract; if I have an object that inherits from "abstractlock", I should be guaranteed that it will have an "unlock()" method, because that is the interface you declared. The "combinationlock" class does not honour that interface, hence PHP's error. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle . A class hierarchy is an interface contract and a code reuse mechanism, it is not a taxonomy.